# how i can blocking run script on php page?

Tags: php, database

i used xampp for one php page on Windows.
but i have a problem.

my cod:

```
<?php 
  if ($row["name"] == null)
  {
    echo $row["name"] = 'no name';
  }
  else
  {
    echo $row["name"]; 
  }
?>
```

when:

```
$row["name"] == "<script>alert("HackEd")</script>"
```

script run.

how i can blocking run script on php page?

Comment: Take a look at [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: `"<script>alert("HackEd")</script>"` You'll get an error with that code

Comment: You need to use single quote inside double quotes `"<script>alert('HackEd')</script>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$row['name'] =  "<script>alert('HackEd')</script>";
  if ($row["name"] == null)
  {
      echo $row["name"] = 'no name';
  }
  else
  {
      echo $row['name']= preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $row['name']);
  }
?>
```

You can simple remove what's inside your script tags before you echo the value of your `$row['name']`